# how to count part in chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, parts

how to make table of content look like

```
Chapter 1 
   Part 1 Etude
        1.1 introducion
        1.2 Other title
    Part 2  Something
        1.3 title
        1.4 title 
Chapter 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: In LaTeX's `book` document class, `\part` is usually reserved for a sectioning unit that's even higher than `\chapter`. (Think, "Parts of a book".) In contrast, you would seem to be using "part" as a sectioning unit that's inbetween `\chapter` and `\section`. Please confirm that this is the case; if it's not, please provide more information as to the intended usage.

Comment: In LaTeX terminology, parts contain chapters, not the other way round.  What you want is to rename sections to parts and change the numbering of sections and subsections.

Comment: @nickie - the somewhat unclear aspect of the posting is that "parts" don't seem to have any numbering-related consequences for the units currently numbered 1.1 thru 1.4.

Comment: @Mico, right, the counter for subsections would have to be based on that of chapters, not sections.

Comment: @Mico : my documents class is report, and i want use part as a sectinoning unit as you said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want.  It is based on my previous comment.
I am warning you that I don't like this at all, as it may break a lot of other things...
If you are to use this seriously, what you really should be doing is to make your own document class, based on `report`, with the sectioning that you prefer.

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
% Include the word "Chapter" in the TOC
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      \chaptername{} #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
% Parts are really sections, numbering is based on chapters
\let\c@section\relax
\newcounter{section}[chapter]
\renewcommand\thesection{Part \@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
                                    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                    {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3.5em}}
\let\part\section
% Sections are really subsections, but their numbering is based on chapters
\let\c@subsection\relax
\newcounter{subsection}[chapter]
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                       {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                       {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                       {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\let\section\subsection
\let\l@newsubsection\l@subsection
%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One} Blah blah...
\part{Etude} Blah blah...
\section{Introduction} Blah blah...
\section{Other title} Blah blah...
\part{Something} Blah blah...
\section{Title} Blah blah...
\section{Title} Blah blah...
\chapter{Two} Blah blah...
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: In light of the new answers, I think @egreg's should be the accepted answer to this question.  It's much cleaner than my hack and is expected to have fewer (if any) bad interactions.

Answer (score 7):

With `titlesec` it's easy to add a level.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\subchapter}{straight}[\chapter]
\newcounter{subchapter}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thesubchapter}{\arabic{subchapter}}

\titleformat{\subchapter}[display]
  {\LARGE\bfseries\filcenter}
  {Part \thesubchapter}
  {1ex}
  {}
\titlespacing{\subchapter}{1ex}{0pt}{4ex plus 2ex minus 1ex}

\makeatletter
\let\l@subchapter\l@section
\let\l@section\l@subsection
\let\l@subsection\l@subsubsection
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{A title}
\subchapter{Study}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Other title}
\subchapter{Something}
\section{Title A}
\section{Title B}
\end{document}
```

I just demoted sections to subsections and subsections to subsubsections in the table of contents, making room for the new leve.

[image]

[image]

You can easily add other customizations. My advice is “don't do like this”.

Answer (score 2):

The approach I'm suggesting, for all intents and purposes, resets `\part` to make it behave like a synonym for `\section`, and it redefines the properties of the section- and subsection-related macros to make them conform to the following numbering scheme:

- A "part" number does not contain the "chapter" number as a prefix, and `\part` doesn't increment or reset the number of a `\subsection`.
- A "subsection" number contains the associated "chapter" number as a prefix.
- A `\chapter` commands resets the `\part` and `\subsection` numbers (to zero).

The code below does this, and it also provides commands to (i) automatically prefix the string "Part" to the part numbers in the sectioning headers and the Table of Contents (in a way that doesn't mess with the ability to create cross-references) and (ii) enable the numbering of `\subsubsection`-level headers as the `\section`-level headers have been diverted to act like, well, "parts". You will probably want to fiddle with the indentation levels of the various entries in the ToC.

Finally, note that because `\part` has been set to behave like `\section` and because the `\section`-related commands have *not* been disabled, you can use either `\part` or `\section` in your document to create "part-level" headers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

% Undefine the existing \part and \thepart macros
\let\part\relax    
\let\thepart\relax 
% make \part a synonym for \section
\let\part\section  

\makeatletter
%% The "@seccntformat" command is an auxiliary command;
%% see pp. 26f. of 'The LaTeX Companion,' 2nd. ed.
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}  % default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}% enable indiv. control
}
\newcommand{\section@cntformat}{Part \thesection\quad} % affix "Part" to section number's display
\makeatother

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} % do not affix chapter number to sections
\counterwithout{subsection}{section}
\counterwithin{subsection}{chapter} % reset subsection numbers to chapter level
% raise value of 'secnumdepth' and 'tocdepth' counters by 1
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\addtocounter{tocdepth}{1}

\usepackage{tocloft} % change some parts of the ToC
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter }
\renewcommand\cftsecpresnum{Part } % insert string "Part " before part number
\cftsetindents{chap}{0em}{6em}   % control of indentation
\cftsetindents{sec}{2.25em}{3.75em}
\cftsetindents{subsec}{6em}{2em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsec}{8em}{2.75em}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents    
\chapter{First things first}

\part{Etude}
\subsection{Introduction}
\subsection{Other title}

\section{Something}  % can use either \part or \section command!
\subsection{A title}
\subsubsection{A subordinated title}
\subsection{Another title}
\subsubsection{Still another subordinated title}

\chapter{Next things sometime later}
\end{document}
```